# Trouble configuring access to craft site

Tags: error-message

So I installed Craft and everything via homebrew on a Mac and created a new project (using nitro) in `~/Documents/www/craft`.

I then used Abyss Server to configure a sub-domain on my dyndns address to point to the site with a home directory of `/www/craft/web`.

When I browse to the URL on my Mac, it works fine. I was able to launch the install and can now access /admin/dashboard all using the dyndns url. But when I try to access the site from my Windows 10 laptop (on the same network, btw), I get a 503.

Not sure if I have done something wrong in configuration but it's pretty frustrating that it works on the host computer and not a different one. I have port 80/443 open to the IP of the Mac mini and that works fine (as I can access other sub-domains configured on my dyndns url) and even if that was the problem I wouldn't get a 503 (which means that web traffic can hit it).

I have also configured the host for my Craft site in Abyss Server to handle PHP. Again, really strange that I can access it via the URL from the Mac but not from the URL on my windows laptop. Hopefully, this is something stupid I'm doing and can be fixed easily. Thanks for any help!

Here is my stack-trace:

> craft\web\ServiceUnavailableHttpException in /Users/jasonthibeault/Documents/www/craft/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php:555
> Stack trace:
> #0 /Users/jasonthibeault/Documents/www/craft/craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(185): craft\web\Application->_processInstallRequest()
> #1 /Users/jasonthibeault/Documents/www/craft/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(392): craft\web\Application->handleRequest()
> #2 /Users/jasonthibeault/Documents/www/craft/craft/web/index.php(26): yii\base\Application->run()
> #3 {main}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a nitro expert but from nitro documentation page:

> By default, your Nitro sites are only available to the machine you’re
> on. This avoids permissions problems  with Docker and protects your
> development projects from potentially-unwanted access from other
> computers.

You can use [nitro's bridge command](https://craftcms.com/docs/nitro/2.x/local-sharing.html) to solve this problem

Comment: Yup, that fixed it (well, at least by IP). I'm not an nitro expert either but now I know that a lot of stuff like this can probably be answered in their documentation. Thanks again, really appreciate it.